# Giving Active Directory users a common-shared home folder

Tags: active-directory

I have an Active Directory running on windows server 2008 R2.

Everytime a user logs on a Windows Computer it creates a home directory (C:/Users/$username).

I want that all Active Directory users have the same home directory.

I.e: user1, user2, user3...usern use "C:/Users/user" folder as home directory.

Is that possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but why would you do it this way? Why wouldn't you just create a group policy to map a drive letter to this network share instead of making it their home directory?

Comment: Take a look at [this question, and my answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/513581/linux-microsoft-active-directory-and-home-folders). Everything I said about why doing this on a Unix system is a terrible idea is true for Windows as well.

Comment: @voretaq7 what's even more "funny", is the same user asked that question.

Comment: @Rex , it´s not funny, we have Windows and Linux servers, so I need to know how to do it both ways.

Comment: @hecstevez the point is, you shouldn't do this on either platform. It's a bad idea. One the windows side, if they don't need home folders, don't set their accounts to use one. Use a policy to to create a mapped drive to the same location for all the users.

Comment: @Rex you should post that (along with the reasons why) as an answer...

Comment: If you want them to have the same local profile (which is what you really are referring to), why have multiple users/accounts?  Let them all log in with the same account.

Comment: TheCleaner, we need to log activities done on servers by users.  

Rex, Voretaq7, why is that such a bad idea?

Comment: @Rex, if I create a group policy to map a drive letter, would that disable the home directory auto creation?

Comment: why have different user accounts at all if this is what you want to do? Why not just give everyone one user account and share the password. The net result is the same.

Comment: As I said a couple of comments ago, we need to log activities done on servers by users. Believe me, we are 100% sure that what I asked is what we need (I don´t mean to be rude btw). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about the `C:\users\%username%` folder, you are talking about a users local profile directory.  There are a few things you can do to here.  A combination of the below things will give you something that is close to having a single local profile.

- Setup [folder redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx) to have documents, desktop, favorites etc directed to a single common folder on a server or elsewhere.
- Profile handling

  - Setup a [mandatory profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that applies to all users.  A single profile is used by all users, but no modifications are permitted by users.  All changes are lost at logout
  - [Roaming profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738596%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) permit profiles per-user but they are copied to a file server of your choice and can be cleared off the local machines at logout.
  - Setup [automatic deletion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173870) of roaming profiles.

Comment: Ty, let me try this and I´ll come back with results!